# Web app runs super slow after AWSSupport-ResetAccess

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-systems-manager

Here's what happened:

1. I spun up an EC2 instance
2. I successfully installed [Ghost](https://ghost.org/) on it (a self-hosted blogging platform)
3. I lost my *.pem private key that gives me access to the EC2 intance
4. I ran the [AWSSupport-ResetAccess](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/automation-awssupport-resetaccess.html)
    automation service to recover the password
5. I successfully recovered the password

However, if I open any page on my blog now, it takes more than 10 seconds to load. In my admin dashboard, I can't make any edit - it returns server errors every time I hit save.

I know that there can be many reasons for the cause of this lag, but I thought to ask this question in case this is a common problem? Is the AWS System Manager known to cause this lag to EC2 instances after an automation flow is executed?

I'm running a t2.micro Ubuntu 18.04 machine in the "eu-west-2" region.

Comment: If you run "top" is anything using excessive CPU? In Cloudwatch does your instance have available CPU / EBS credits or is it running on baseline CPU? A stop / start of the instance might be worthwhile - stop/start is different from a restart in AWS.

Comment: Doesn't look like anything unusual to me, [here's a screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/0CnYEO7). I'll try stop it and start it again, I didn't know that's different to a restart.

Comment: Update: nah, stopping and starting didn't help. It's as low as before :(. FWIW I also tried updating all Linux packages and Ghost itself, didn't help. The AWS ResetAccess cannot be a coincidence ..

Comment: Also, this is what it shows when I run `top`: [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/WYE5TsX).

Comment: Interesting. Check your EBS burst balance. You could restore an EBS snapshot to another instance to compare performance, but if you can't log in maybe not helpful. You could build a new instance and migrate your data over to see if it helps. I think the answer to your question is "no it doesn't do that", and there's not enough information to help with the performance issue.

Comment: Thanks Tim for your insights. I will answer my question if I figure out what's the problem.